# Use hint only if condition is met

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, hint

My PL/SQL function does an insert into a table:

```
procedure MY_PROC(n in number default null) is
begin
    insert into MY_TABLE T
    select ...
    from ...;
end;
```

My problem is: if `n` is null, the query is very slow and I found that using the `materialize` hint (yes I know it's undocumented) solves the problem. BUT if `n` is not null then the query, which was fast, is now slow because of this hint !

So is there a way to use a hint only if a condition is met ? I tought about using dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) but I would like to avoid this.

Thanks !

Comment: How do you know that the `materialize` hint solves your problem? Have you compared the execution plans to see why?

Comment: Well, the execution time is a good parameter, isn't it ? 10s against several minutes...

Comment: Do you know how the plans will scale with realistic and varying data volumes and input parameters? If you don't know what the plan is, you don't have a clue as to how it will behave with varying conditions. Adding a hint just because it seemed to make it faster in one instance is not a reliable method of tuning the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write two insert statements, one with the hint and one without it, and seperate them with a

```
if n is null then
   ... statement with hint
else
   ... statement without hint
end if;
```